# Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string. REACT problem

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, request, frontend

I'm a newbie in react and I'm trying to make a GET request to my own API and then render the result on the screen. When I do that, I `console.log` my result as well and in the console I get it right, but I can't put it on my screen. I was using `useState` for this.

My code:

```
const url = "http://localhost:2000/appShop";
const [shop, showShop] = useState("");

const getShop = () => {
    Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      showShop(response.data.name + response.data.address + response.data.city);
    });
  };


<Box
            sx={{
              "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
            }}

          >
            <span>{shop}</span>
            <Button onClick={getShop}>List all Shops</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => showShopCard(false)}>Close</Button>
</Box>
```

The result I get is here:
[image]

I get it in console, but not on my screen

Comment: You  should return your <Box>

Comment: @NiceBooks can you be more specific?

Comment: `response.data` is an array as your log shows, and it doesn't have `name`, `address`, etc. You get `NaN` because your have `undefined + undefined + undefined`

Comment: @tromgy but how do i take it then? Thought that my path "response.data" was correct

Comment: @miloš-milutinov Your code is inside a React Component. Components should return React elements (<Box> is a React element). The error seems to imply that your Component is not returning a React element. Can you show the return part of your component ?

Comment: It's been solved @NiceBooks, thanks tho. And yes, i did return box, i just didn't copy it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response.data is an array.
You need to loop through the array and save the result in a state, moreover you need to create a span item for each element in the array:

```
const url = "http://localhost:2000/appShop";
const [shop, showShop] = useState("");
const [shopList, setShopList] = useState([]);

const getShop = () => {
    Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      const shopListItems = [];
      response.data.forEach(resItem => {
        shopListItems.push(resItem.name + resItem.address + resItem.city)
      })
      setShopList(shopListItems)
    });
  };


<Box
            sx={{
              "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
            }}

          >
            {shopList.map((sl, index) => (<span key={index}>{sl}</span>))}
            <Button onClick={getShop}>List all Shops</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => showShopCard(false)}>Close</Button>
</Box>
```